# Complexity of generating a prime larger than $N$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Is it provably difficult to generate a prime larger than a prescribed $N$? For instance, if I want a prime of $1000$ digits, is there a way to do that deterministically, i.e., without resorting to AKS and exhaustive search?

Comment: Side note: exhaustively searching for a prime is (usually) deterministic

Comment: That's true. I meant to say an algorithm with bounded time of termination where the bound is a function of N.

Comment: ...? So, you want it to be O(f(N)) for some function $f$? That's always trivially doable.

Comment: There are algorithms to construct provable primes. See e.g. 
**4.62 Algorithm Maurer’s algorithm for generating provable primes**
in A. Menezes, P. van Oorschot, S. Vanstone: Handbook of
Applied Cryptography (http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's unknown if there is an algorithm that can compute a prime larger than $N$ in polynomial time (that is, $O((\log{N})^k)$ for some k). [Cramér's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture) implies that exhausitive search (counting up from $N+1$ and testing with AKS) runs in polynomial time.